# Silverlight: Docking of controls

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, controls, docking

Is it possible to dock Silverlight based controls like Windows Forms control ?
For example I want to use a tab control, which I want to use as a control for page navigation ! Unfortunately I don't find a "Dock" property :-( !

Comment: +1 Good question! I struggled with this one for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight Toolkit found on Codeplex contains a `DockPanel` control, you will want to use that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that i understand your question, but you can consider using one of the various WPF layout [techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx).

Example:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Bottom</Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left">Left</Button>        
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">Right</Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top">Top</Button>
    <Button>Fill</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Especially I want to dock silverlight controls. In Windows Forms you can dock every control in its container !

Comment: The Silverlight Toolkit on Codeplex has such a DockPanel ! I think it behaves like the WPF DockPanel... !?

Comment: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-DockPanel-in-Silverlight-2.aspx

http://allaboutasp.net/2009/04/silverlight-layout-container-panels-dock-panel/

Maybe this will help

Comment: +1 This code works fine when used against the Silverlight Toolkit version of `DockPanel`

Answer (score 1):

[**DockPanel**](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @Kottan: When you use the WPF tag in your question you will draw WPF answers, if you are looking for a strictly Silvelight answer remove the WPF tag from the question.