# Docking of Silverlight Controls

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, docking

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266185/silverlight-docking-of-controls) question, but still, it explains how to dock controls within DockPanel.  How does one dock the DockPanel within the window?
[image]

As you can see, the Map control is docked to the DockPanel, but the DockPanel is not docked to the window.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I'm missing the question... Do you want the DockPanel to fill the Window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties from the `DockPanel`, the default for these properties is `Stretch` which will cause the `DockPanel` to fill the available space.